# Sveltekit how do I set checkboxes checked based on query params?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to set checkboxes active based on query parameters using Sveltekit. To achieve this, I tried to get all route query parameters using the 'url.searchParams.entries()' method to get all query parameters from the URL.

Then I am trying to loop through all the params and then loop through all posts and check if the value of the query param is equal to a value in posts. If so, it should set checked to true forEach checkbox that meets the value. Then in my HTML, I bind the checked variable to my checkbox. But the issue is that when I put in 4 in the query params (or select 4 using the checkbox), it checks all the checkboxes but, if I select any of the other checkboxes, it doesn't do a single thing (besides from querying data from the JSON placeholder api)

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2">         
   {#each posts as post}
      <div class="col-span-1">
         <input type="checkbox" bind:checked={checked} value={post.id} bind:group= 
           {selectedPosts} on:change="{() => updateValue(post.id)}" class="mr-2">
      </div>
      <div class="col-span-1">
         <label for="{post.id}">{post.id}</label>
      </div>
      {/each}
 </div>
```

This is inside my script tag:

```
import { filter, results } from '../../stores.js';
    import { page } from '$app/stores';

    let checked = false
    let selectedPosts = []
    const posts = [
        { 
            name: 'post',
            id:'1' 
        }, 
        { 
            name: 'post',
            id: '2'
        }, 
        {
            name: 'post',
            id: '3'
        },
        {
            name: 'post',
            id: '4'
        }
    ]
    
    $:  {
        //If the query params would be '?posts=1', the output would be ['posts', '1']
        let params = [...$page.url.searchParams.entries()]
        
        params.forEach(param => {
            //Returns the first param. In this case '1'
            let value = param[1]

            posts.forEach(post => {
                if(post.id === value){
                    console.log('true')
                    checked = true
                } else {
                    checked = false
                    console.log('false')
                }
            })
        });
    }
        

    async function updateValue(value) {
        
        filter.set(value)
    }
```

In my store I set the query params like so:

```
export const results = derived(filter, (value) => {
    if(!value) return {};
    const data = fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${value}`).then(res => {
        return res.json()
    })

    return data
});


filter.subscribe(value => {
    if(!value) return 
    goto(`/activiteiten/filter?post=${value.toString()}`)
    return value
})
```

And finally I return with a derived store some data from the JSON placeholder API.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `bind:checked={checked}` when using `bind:group`. I think this is the root of your problem. You are setting the same `checked` variable for every item.

```
if(post.id === value){
  console.log('true')
  checked = true
} else {
  checked = false
  console.log('false')
}
```

When you later check based on this variable, you get unexpected behavior.